# JAVA error: package com/... does not exist

Tags: java, package, classpath

I created a simple tic-tac-toe game, and put some functions on another package, so i can import them on my Main function.

When i run on eclipse IDE, i have no problem, but when i try run on windows CMD i get the following error: [console log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STsIm.png)

Here is my folder structure: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Blto.png)

initial code of Main class, with imports:

```
package com.github.vitucomment.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.github.vitucomment.players.PlayersFunctions;
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.BoardFunctions;
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.GameRulesFunctions;
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.ScoreFunctions;


public class Main {
```

Console log error:

```
C:\Users\victo\eclipse-workspace\Java-JogoDaVelha\src\com\github\vitucomment\main>java Main.java
Main.java:6: error: package com.github.vitucomment.players does not exist
import com.github.vitucomment.players.PlayersFunctions;
                                     ^
Main.java:7: error: package com.github.vitucomment.utils does not exist
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.BoardFunctions;
                                   ^
Main.java:8: error: package com.github.vitucomment.utils does not exist
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.GameRulesFunctions;
                                   ^
Main.java:9: error: package com.github.vitucomment.utils does not exist
import com.github.vitucomment.utils.ScoreFunctions;
                                   ^
Main.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
        public static PlayersFunctions playersFunctions() {
                      ^
  symbol:   class PlayersFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ScoreFunctions scoreFunctions() {
                      ^
  symbol:   class ScoreFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
        public static BoardFunctions boardFunctions() {
                      ^
  symbol:   class BoardFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
        public static GameRulesFunctions gameRulesFunctions() {
                      ^
  symbol:   class GameRulesFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                PlayersFunctions playersFunctions = playersFunctions();
                ^
  symbol:   class PlayersFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
                return new PlayersFunctions();
                           ^
  symbol:   class PlayersFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                return new ScoreFunctions();
                           ^
  symbol:   class ScoreFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
                return new BoardFunctions();
                           ^
  symbol:   class BoardFunctions
  location: class Main
Main.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
                return new GameRulesFunctions();
                           ^
  symbol:   class GameRulesFunctions
  location: class Main
13 errors
error: compilation failed
```

I don't know how to fix it, before change to packages it was working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

CMD run project
make a file  x.bat
copy Code change you config

```html
@echo on
@title E:\projectPath
@set dir_path=E:\libPath
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for %%i in (%dir_path%\*.jar,%dir_path%\lib\*.jar) do (
@set other_path=!other_path!;%%i
)
set classpath= %other_path%
@java package.Main
```

Comment: How can i do that? Where i find the x.bat file and configure it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).